# Saving a relationship on BOTH ends in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember Data with the RestAdapter and the following models:

```
Pizzas.Pizza = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  orders: DS.hasMany('order', { async: true }),
});

Pizzas.Order = DS.Model.extend({
  date: DS.attr('date'),
  pizzas: DS.hasMany('pizza', { async: true }),
});
```

I create and save a new order as follows:

```
var pizza1 = an existing pizza with id 1;
var pizza2 = an existing pizza with id 2;

var newOrder = this.store.createRecord('order');
newOrder.set('date', Date());

newOrder.get('pizzas').then(function(pizzas) {

    pizzas.pushObject(pizza1);
    pizzas.pushObject(pizza2);
    newOrder.save();
});
```

This works well - Ember Data performs a POST on the `Order` model which include the ids of the pizzas in the `pizzas` relationship field. However, I expected that following the save, the order id would be automatically added to the `orders` relationship of the 2 pizza objects by Ember Data, but that appears not to be the case. This causes 2 issues:

1. When I ask for all the orders for a pizza, the new order does not appear (since it was never added to the relationship field of the pizza)
2. When a change is made to a pizza (e.g. name change) and the pizza saved, the new order relationship is lost on the server (since it was never added to the relationship field of the pizza and the PUT only includes the order ids last fetched from the server)

I solve this by amending the last line of code above as follows:

```
newOrder.save().then(function() {

        pizza1.get('orders').then(function(orders) {

            orders.pushObject(newOrder);
        })
        // same for pizza 2
    } );
```

***Does Ember data require that the relationship be created manually on both sides (as I am doing) or am I missing something?***

Comment: I think this is expected behavior. You're defining relationships, not absolute constraints. hasMany() simply means that - it can have many; not 'a pizza in this order must also add the order to the pizza's orders list'. It would be very strange for the framework to do this under the hood.

Comment: @PrasadSilva I disagree that this is expected. I created [Ember-Graph](https://github.com/gordonkristan/ember-graph) to solve this exact issue. If it only updated on one end, it wouldn't be a relationship, it would just be a reference. OP - What version of Ember-Data are you using? I don't think the single source of truth branch got merged until beta 9 or 10.

Comment: @GJK Thanks for your reply. We are on 9, but are moving to 11 tomorrow. We've had a few issues, so hopefully that will fix it. Will post an update here once done

Comment: From the changelog, it seems like the relationship changes didn't get added until beta 10. You're likely to have to make a bunch of changes to upgrade, but the issue you're experiencing should go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using beta 11 plus patches from my own fork.

Persisting relationships is something you will need to manage yourself. There can't be any hard or fast rules in Ember Data about this because different servers and json apis will have different approaches to managing relationships as well as specific validation and referential integrity rules which will dictate how relationships between models should be managed.  This will introduce ordering dependencies into your model persistence stategies.  If you have a lax "NoSQL" type document server that has no such referential integrity requirements then things will appear easy at first, with the eventual reality of data inconsistencies, orphans, dangling references and so on.

Be careful about client side data persistence layers that claim to solve your problems, as in reality they can only work on some narrow use cases. Its really just a matter of orchestrating the save in your controllers where the knowledge and the context of what needs to be done belongs.

A strategy I have found works well in json apis is to simply manage relationships on the model that has the foreign key (ie the "belongsTo" side) and avoid returning or managing keys on the hasMany side as all those id's being passed around don't scale well when your collections grow.

It is best to look at the source for the [JSONSerializer](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L459) base class where models are serialized to see what it does, the [RESTSerializer](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js) inherits its behaviour.  You will see that the serializer just saves ids, and does not recursively cascade saves through your object graph, which would be a bad thing as you would be trying to solve the [NP-Complete Hamiltonian Path Problem!](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js).  This is why I say be VERY suspicious of data layers making promises to solve your model graph persistence problem and instead just orchestrate what you know needs to be done in your controllers. This also aligns very well with dirty tracking and buffering changes (eg using [a buffered proxy](https://github.com/movableink/buffered-proxy)).

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add something rather obvious, but you can define your own model serializers that can side-save any related models as part of a single POST/PUT transaction (rather than using a `.then` approach), depending on what your server supports. Just override the relevant serialize method to include what you need.  The [EmbeddedRecordsMixin](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/embedded_records_mixin.js) can also be useful if you have some very closely related models that are always created or updated together.

For example, I have Contact model, where each Contact can have one or more Names, Addresses, Emails, or Urls. And each of those are models themselves that track preference/purpose, as well as validFrom/validTo and so on.

Firstly my application serializer mixes in the embedded records support and merging of the `attrs` property so I can inherit serializers:

```
// app/serializers/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
  mergedProperties: [ 'attrs' ]
});
```

Then my Contact serializer specifies what models are embedded:

```
// app/serializers/contact.js
import AppSerializer from "./application";

export default AppSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    names: { embedded: 'always'},
    addresses: { embedded: 'always' },
    emails: { embedded: 'always' },
    phones: { embedded: 'always' },
    urls: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```